# Error libx264 not found

Tags: software-installation

I follow this installation [guide](http://lynckia.com/licode/install.html). At step 3 (Install Dependencies):

> `sudo ./licode/scripts/installUbuntuDeps.sh` in terminal

But while compiling it throws `error libx264 not found` Why I got this error, and how to solve it?

Comment: It is a video decoding package and can be installed with `sudo apt-get install libx264-142 libx264-dev`

Comment: @123456 You should add that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happens because you are compiling libav with `--enable-libx264` which would need the libx264 headers to complete. It fails at the configure phase with:

```
configure: error: libx264 not found
```

This can be fixed easily installing the needed headers package `libx264-dev` which should be done with `sudo apt-get install yasm libvpx. libx264.` but for some reason it doesn't for you:

```
sudo apt-get install yasm libvpx. libx264.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libvpx-doc' for regex 'libvpx.'
Note, selecting 'libvpx1-dbg' for regex 'libvpx.'
Note, selecting 'libvpx-dev' for regex 'libvpx.'
Note, selecting 'libvpx1' for regex 'libvpx.'
Note, selecting 'libx264-133' for regex 'libx264.'
Note, selecting 'libx264-142' for regex 'libx264.'
Note, selecting 'libx264-dev' for regex 'libx264.'
libvpx-dev is already the newest version.
libvpx1 is already the newest version.
libvpx1 set to manually installed.
yasm is already the newest version.
libx264-142 is already the newest version.
libx264-142 set to manually installed.
libx264-dev is already the newest version.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvpx-doc libvpx1-dbg
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,613 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,027 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Comment: I thought it has been solved but I got this:
Unable to locate package libx264 after using sudo apt-get install yasm libvpx. libx264

Comment: @MoathHowari it has a point at the end `libx264.`

Comment: Yep you are right, Ill run installUbuntuDeps.sh again now,and see if the error still appears or not. thanks

Comment: @Braiam I'm going to compile ffmpeg for ARM processor. So I can't install it as that way, because that way install for my PC. I should add compiled x264 folder for ARM, in ./configure command; I added this like: --extra-cflags="-I../x264" --extra-ldflags="-L../x264"; But seems doesn't work.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde I'm not knowledgeable about ARM's builds but don't you have a -dev package that includes those headers? IMO, ffmpeg configure script should find it.

Comment: @Braiam I have x264 header and .a library and .pc files; And all of the located in x264 folder side by ffmpeg folder. But seems can't find them. Even I copied files to /usr/local/include , /usr/local/lib ; But can't find them again!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde did you check https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi? Maybe you need to crosscompile instead of trying to compile it directly on the ARM device?

Comment: @Braiam I did not compile ffmpeg on ARM! I compile it on Linux; for ARM. And without "--enable-libx264" parameter, I compiled it successfully for ARM. I have even do this patch(https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg/blob/master/enable-fake-pkg-config.patch), but not helpful. I still get "ERROR: libx264 not found". BTW, if I remove that parameter, I still see D.V.LS h264 (when run ffmpeg -codecs)

Answer (score 1):

include  --enable-static **--disable-opencl**

eg -

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://download.videolan.org/pub/x264/snapshots/last_x264.tar.bz2
tar xjvf last_x264.tar.bz2
cd x264-snapshot*
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-static **--disable-opencl**
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" make
make install
make distclean
```

Comment: Thanks, but does anyone understand why this works?

Comment: This installs libx264 from source, though you should usually use the package manager to install software.

Answer (score 0):

AS **123456** said use `sudo apt-get install libx264-142 libx264-dev`

This will install the libx264 that gave you the error.